# How to have the Layout convert a Page written in Markdown to HTML (using Zurb Foundation Panini)

Tags: zurb-foundation, markdown

I am using Zurb's Panini site generator. I am using a CMS that outputs a html file written in markdown to the pages folder. My goal was to have the template file convert the markdown to html.

I've tried to have the markdown get converted before it enters the template file but haven't found a way with the CMS I am using (NetlifyCMS). The CMS also needs to be very user friendly for non-technical users.

```
<!-- This is the part of the template file -->
<article class="cell medium-5 cell-block-y location-info-container">
    <h1 class="location">{{title}}</h1>
    {{#markdown}}
    {{> body}}
    {{/markdown}}
</article>
```

When running `foundation build` everything works as expected except for the markdown content is still markdown. I have tried to find a workaround but with no luck so I am open to a solution or workaround. Also, a quick apology in advanced, due to client restrictions I am unable to post links and have the project on a private repository.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a markdown helper using `marked` or another markdown library.

https://github.com/zurb/panini/blob/dev/readme.md